# « y croire » ou « le croire »

Tags: grammaire, pronoms

On imagine que je dis

> Est-ce que tu crois que c'est fait de fromage, la lune ?

Est-ce que le réponse affirmative est

> Oui, je le crois.

ou

> Oui, j'y crois.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dans ce cas particulier, on dira *je le crois*. Le pronom prépositionnel *y* s'emploie lorsqu'il faut remplacer un groupe prépositionnel avec *à* (groupe qui est alors un complément indirect), mais ici la construction emploie un complément direct sous la forme d'une proposition subordonnée, et dans ce cas, c'est le pronom *le* qu'on emploie.

Comment: merci. Alors, c'est juste que j'ai entendu « j'y crois » dans beaucoup de chansons: par exemple, « je me dit que c'est toi, et je sais que tu y crois ». ça remplace quoi, le « y » ?

Comment: @hunter Dans ce cas, *y* ne réfère pas à la phrase précédente, mais probablement à quelque chose de sous-entendu, auquel cas les deux pronoms sont possibles. On peut compléter l'exclamation *je n'arrive pas à...* autant par *le croire* que par *y croire*.